# Would SQL Server be hit when an IQueryable made from a list is again converted to a list?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working on a platform and it has the below situation.

```
IQueryable<customer> q1 =  ef expression;
IList<customer> l1 = q1.ToList();

IQueryable<entity> q2 = l1.select(c => c.customerrId) AsQueryable();
IList<customer> l2 = q2.ToList();
```

Would the `q2.toList()` execute a query again in SQL Server?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?  Should be straightforward to test this.

Comment: Try SQL Server Profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% but I believe that the database would not be hit again. Once you enumerate a collection it forces the data into memory. Even if you set it as a `Queryable` object again.

But like others are saying, check SQL server when you run the query to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have tested with profiler to understand this. it is not hitting database again for the q2.toList()

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to anything performance related, always profile, never rely on advice since it could easily go out of date. Profile your code and your database and see what happens with some simple test code.

You can use [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) to see what queries are made and how long they take.